# Redirect all traffic bar one directory to an index.html page

Tags: .htaccess

I have an existing WordPress site where I want to redirect everything, bar one directory, to a holding page.

I have an .htaccess file and the directory to exclude is /SupportPortal.

This is a completely separate WordPress installation that I want to keep up and running.

The holding page is index.html

I am using the below but getting weird results where it is downloading a file, not sure what it is, when I visit any url on the site

Redirect looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirect everything to holding-page/index.html except /SupportPortal
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SupportPortal
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

The file it is downloading is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Comment: Where exactly have you put this rule? Is `/SupportPortal` part of the "existing WordPress" site (a WP URL)? Or is it a physical directory with it's own files? So, you need to exclude `/SupportPortal/<anything>`? Does this "SupportPortal" not use any assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) outside of this "directory"? Does your "holding page" (`index.html`) not use any external assets either? You shouldn't be 301 redirecting to what is presumably a _temporary_ "holding page". A 301 is _permanent_ and cached  persistently by the browser (and intermediary) caches.

Comment: /SupportPortal is a separate WP installation

It is downloading a file, the contents of which I have added to my original question

Thanks